# Add do_shortcode to printf in WordPress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to make a 'Copyright text' Customizer field render shortcodes.
The field is rendered via `footer.php` so I can override the original code in my child theme.
The code uses `printf` that fetches the content input from a field in Customizer options like so:

```
<?php printf( wp_kses_post(__( '%s', 'slim' )), Slim_Opt::getOption( 'footer_copyright_text', 'Slim - eCommerce WP Theme' )); ?>
```

I've tried adding do_shortcode around `wp_kses_post` as well as around the whole contents of `printf`, but it didn't work.
I've tried replacing printf with `echo do_shortcode`, but it didn't work either.

Is there a way to keep this code for retrieving the setting value from Customizer and also rendering any shortcodes that might be within that value?

Comment: Try this: `<?php $footer_option = do_shortcode( Slim_Opt::getOption( 'footer_copyright_text', 'Slim - eCommerce WP Theme' ) );  printf( wp_kses_post(__( '%s', 'slim' )), $footer_option ); ?>` This will process the customizer field first, then pass it to the `printf`

Comment: Thank you, @disinfor ! That works great, both with and without setting a variable. Please post it as an answer so I can select it as _the answer_!

Comment: Added as an answer! I'm glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `shortcode` to work, it needs to be processed first from the customizer option - or you can just output the option using `do_shortcode`

1. No variable option:

```
echo do_shortcode( Slim_Opt::getOption( 'footer_copyright_text', 'Slim - eCommerce WP Theme' ) );
```

2. Or, you can hold the output in a variable:

```
<?php $footer_option = do_shortcode( Slim_Opt::getOption( 'footer_copyright_text', 'Slim - eCommerce WP Theme' ) ); 
printf( wp_kses_post(__( '%s', 'slim' )), $footer_option ); ?>
```

Either way works, just depends on if you want it to pass to `wp_kses_post()`.